# Can I use different transformations on features to ensure my data follow Gaussian Distribution

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, data-transformation, boxcox-transformation

Suppose I am doing linear regression on a dataset. My dataset contains columns $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, \text{target}$. Features (independent variables) are the column names starting with "f" and my target variable (dependent variable) is "target".

Suppose that $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$, and $\text{target}$ are continuous variables and require data transformation to look like a Gaussian distribution. (As this is an assumption of most of the linear models)

Now, I see that there is no one transformation that fixes all of those. For some, Yeo-Johnson did the job, for others I had to use something different. Similarly for target variables, I had to use something different. Suppose a Box-Cox transformation or quantile transformation.

Is it a legit approach? Or do I need to use a single or same transformer for all the features?

Comment: Linear models do *not* require predictors to be normally distributed.

Comment: My mistake, I called my predictors dependent variables. Or Do you mean that my features [f1, ... f4] do not require to follow normal distribution?

Comment: aren't machine learning algorithms like Linear Regression and Gaussian Naive Bayes assume the numerical variables have a Gaussian probability distribution?

Comment: modern day linear regression was invented *before* the gaussian distribution.

Comment: The Gaussian was arguably invented or discovered by de Moivre, and that was before regression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The Assumptions of Normality

Regression does not require normality of either the predictors or the outcome. The typical assumption is that the *residuals* are normally distributed. Even this on its own isn't totally damning for your regression, but can be depending on the severity of the issue. The main thing is to map the proper functional relationship between the predictors and the response. The residuals usually give hints about where certain mis-specifications may arise, but that does not necessarily require variables in the regression to be normally distributed.

The book *[Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.4324/9780203774441/applied-multiple-regression-correlation-analysis-behavioral-sciences-jacob-cohen-patricia-cohen-stephen-west-leona-aiken)* has a section on assumptions dedicated to this (p.148-151):

> **Finally, for any value of the independent variable X, the residuals around the regression line are assumed to have a normal distribution.** Violations of the normality assumption do not lead to bias in estimates of the regression coefficients. The effect of violation of the normality assumption on significance tests and confidence intervals depends on the sample size, with problems occurring in small samples. In large samples, nonnormality of the residuals does not lead to serious problems with the interpretation of either significance tests or confidence intervals. However, nonnormal residuals are often an important signal of other problems in the regression model (e.g., misspecification-using an incorrect regression model) and can help guide appropriate remedial actions.

Note that they make this distinction about residuals multiple times in the Cohen book (here p.277, where the author even italicizes "residuals" to make that point clear):

> **Recall that inference in OLS regression assumes that *residuals* are normally distributed.** If we analyze a data set with OLS regression and find that residuals are not normally distributed, for example, by examining a Q-Q plot of residuals against a normal variate (Section 4.3), then transformation of $Y$ may be in order. Skew in the dependent variable may well be the source of the skewed residuals. Our approach, then, is to transform the DV in the hopes of achieving more normal residuals.

There is an excellent discussion about the assumptions required in linear regression in [*Regression and Other Stories*](https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/), including which ones are more important over others (I believe discussion starts around p.153-155), with relevant discussion about normality of *residuals* below. Note that Gelman et al. have a different view on how important this assumption really is:

> The distribution of the error term is relevant when predicting
> individual data points. For the purpose of estimating the regression line (as compared to predicting individual data points), **the assumption of normality is typically barely important at all**. Thus we do not recommend diagnostics of the normality of regression residuals. For example, many textbooks recommend quantile-quantile (Q-Q) plots, in which the ordered residuals are plotted vs. the corresponding expected values of ordered draws from a normal distribution, with departures of this plot from linearity indicating nonnormality of the error term. There is nothing wrong with making such a plot, and it can be relevant when evaluating the use of the model for predicting individual data points, but we are typically more concerned with the assumptions of validity, representativeness, additivity, linearity, and so on, listed above.

Nowhere in either book do they mention that normality of the distribution of predictors or outcome necessary, only discussions on residuals. Keep in mind that part of the reason why you would normally not want to transform your data by default is because you want your predictors to be interpretable. It is much harder to interpret a coefficient which has a square root transformation applied to the data blindly rather than the original data functionally represented in the regression.

##### A Practical Example

Suppose we have two variables which have the following distributions:

[image]

We can see that our $x$ is right-skewed and our $y$ is left-skewed. However, their scatterplot shows this relationship:

[image]

There is clearly *something* driving this relationship...$y$ increases rapidly with initial increases in $x$, then sharply falls off. This is because the functional relationship behind this simulated data can best be represented as:

$$
y = \text{log(x)} + \epsilon
$$

Fitting this relationship in our regression gets us the red line shown in the plot. Now the residuals will give us hints about whether we have really mis-calibrated our regression, which here clearly can be easily done if fitting this with a simple line. So we check our residuals. Are our residuals "healthy?"

[image]

They certainly are, and demonstrate that having normally distributed predictors or outcomes isn't that important for fitting regressions. Having normally distributed *residuals* gives clues that our regression has fit correctly. How much this matters case by case, but the above example should make that clear. Relevant R code for this example is found below for those curious.

##### R Code

```
#### Simulate Data ####
set.seed(123)
x <- rbeta(1000,1,2)
y <- log(x) + rnorm(1000,sd=.3)

#### Plot Histograms ####
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(x)
hist(y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

#### Plot Scatter ####
plot(x,y,
     main="Simulated Data")

#### Get Prediction Data ####
fit <- lm(y ~ log(x))

newdata <- data.frame(
  x = seq(
    min(x),
    max(x),
    length.out=200
  )
)

pred <- predict(fit,newdata=newdata)

lines(newdata$x,
      pred,
      col="darkred",
      lwd=3)

#### Plot Residuals ####
hist(resid(fit),
     main="Histogram of Residuals")
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your response.
Doesn't linear regression assume that numerical variables have Gaussian probability distribution?

Comment: I have made a couple edits to my previous answer to make my point even more clear.

Comment: I am amazed with your response. Thank you!!

Comment: Ideal conditions here are about errors, not residuals. Naturally, the residuals are our best guess at the errors.  Gelman and friends are closer to the  mark here. I don't follow their advice minimizing the value of normal quantile plots, which aren't essential or the most needed graphs, but they can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Shawn Hemelstrand has an extensive frame challenge on your belief that the predictors need to be normal, but I didn't see them addressing your main question.

Using different transformations for different columns is not without any danger. It can make your predictors less powerful, and by introducing more parameters, you can increase the risk of overfitting. And if the original predictors did have normal residuals, the new ones might not, but that's an issue even if you use the same transformation.

But there is no rule in general that you have to use the same transformations. If you find a measure that gives you good predictions, that's what matters.